# Is \n supported in the value of the property, while creating a node in tinkergraph?

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to store a json array as a property for a node created in the tinkergraph.

```
    public void testnewLine() {
        String Value = "[{\n" +
                "            \"detailAccountType\": 5120,\n" +
                "            \"name\": \"Ventes dep roduits résiduels en France\",\n" +
                "            \"id\": 3,\n" +
                "            \"accountNumber\": \"70301\",\n" +
                "            \"fullyQualifiedName\": \"Ventes de produits fabriqués, prestations de services, marchandises: Ventes de produits résiduels: Ventes de produits résiduels en France\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "]";
        String query = String.format("g.addV('test').property('value', '%s').project('b')", Value);
        List<Result> result = helper.getQueryUtils().executeQuery(query);
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);
        String deleteQuery = "g.V().hasLabel('test').drop()";
        helper.getQueryUtils().executeQuery(deleteQuery);
    }
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Script5.groovy: 1: expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 1, column 37.
   g.addV('test').property('value', '[{
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a String API to send your queries, you'll have to double-escape  character escape sequences. You could, for example, use [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/), but a simple `String::replaceAll` will do, too:

```
String query = String.format("g.addV('test').property('value', '%s').project('b')",
                             Value.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]", "\\\\n"));
```

However, the best solution in your particular example would be to not use any line-breaks at all, as they don't have a purpose besides making the JSON blob look better to the human eye. I would probably prefer to replace any whitespace sequence with a single whitespace:

```
Value.replaceAll("[\\r\\n\\t ]+", " ")
```

This will only become an issue if the values in you JSON blob use any of these characters and/or escape sequences. In this case, double-escaping is your only choice.